# Can't render action in nested Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, layout

I have Two Layouts, `MainLayout` and 
`SubLayout`. 
`SubLayout` inherits from `MainLayout`.
In MainLayout`I have Section Like this :

```
<ul>
  @RenderSection("LostSection",true)              
</ul>
```

And in `SubLayout` have :

```
<div id="main-content">
@RenderBody()
</div>

@section LostSection{
    @{Html.RenderAction(MVC.Home.ActionNames.NewFind, MVC.Home.Name)}
}
```

and my Action is :

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public virtual ActionResult NewFind()
    {
        var things = _things.NewThings(ThingType.Found).Select(x => new LastThingViewModel {HasReward=x.IsReward,Id=x.Id,Reward=x.Reward,Title=x.Title});

        return PartialView(MVC.Partials.Views._NewFound,things);

    }
```

But when I run the project I get this error:

> Section not defined: "LostSection"

And my other views inherits `SubLayout`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to `SubLayout`:

`@section Header {@RenderSection("LostSection", true)}`

More info: [In MVC Razor, how do you do a RenderSection defined below a sub-layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602432/in-mvc-razor-how-do-you-do-a-rendersection-defined-below-a-sub-layout)